# Do normal elements contain custom elements?

Tags: html

Is there a **[custom elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements)** in the **[normal elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2)** group?

From one chapter I realized that there are several types of groups of elements, the largest is **normal elements**. But I still do not understand whether there are **custom elements**.

The paragraph says:

> **Normal elements:** All other allowed **[HTML elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#html-elements)** are normal elements

[This reference](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#html-elements) says that any definitions in namespace are contained in http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

And also the quote:

> The term "HTML elements" refer to any element in that namespace, even in XML documents.

But here definitions of **custom elements** are not present in http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml, whether means it that **custom elements** is not included in group **normal elements**.

Comment: What difference does it make whether they belong to the set of normal elements or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are normal elements.

Some background: XML has a concept of namespaces which lets two authors use the same element name without  colliding. For example an XML format for dinosaurs might have an "age" element for ages like Jurassic, Cretaceous, etc. and an XML format for patient records might have an "age" element for "how many years old is this person" and you can combine them in one XML document (yay, XML) without problems, despite both elements being called "age", because they come from different namespaces.

HTML has some limited handling of namespaces for backwards compatibility with XHTML and SVG. `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` is the namespace URI for HTML elements; your custom elements are in that namespace. Check out `document.querySelector(...).namespaceURI` in JavaScript to see that is true. An element having that namespace doesn't mean it's an element name defined by the XHTML spec, you can create elements in that namespace with all kinds of element names.

Because autonomous custom elements are in that namespace and aren't those special elements (area, base, etc.) they are normal elements.

What does this mean? It just means that they're parsed a certain way. The HTML spec uses element kinds as a shorthand to specify how child content parsing, self-closing tags, and things like that work for a bunch of elements at once.

Comment: Thanks for answer, even after 9 months :)